# Failed to read length for configuration 1

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I ran the code, I got these error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:57697/devtools/browser/af541b42-1a2f-4e22-9dfd-bb5caefedbc9
[8660:20572:0220/082009.437:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(141)] Failed to read length for configuration 1.
[8660:20572:0220/082009.446:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(100)] Failed to read all configuration descriptors. Expected 2, 
got 1.
[8660:20572:0220/082009.448:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(192)] [08:20:09.441] USB: usb_device_win.cc:95 Failed to read descriptors from \\?\usb#vid_1199&pid_9063#5&9c068d0&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}.
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="fb3e316a4a608b4bcd94ba958e38ad0b", element="2F69BB49F203DE879037862EE5EBE74D_element_59")>
```

How can I resolve this?

BaseClass:

```
def verifyPresence(self, path):
         WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located(path)
            )
 def verifyClickable(self,path):
          WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
              EC.element_to_be_clickable(path)
              )
  def add_item_to_cart(self, ItemName):
        menupage = MenuPage(self.driver)
        self.verifyPresence(menupage.Cards)
        Items = menupage.getCards()
        for item in Items:
            print(f"{item}\n")
            item_name = menupage.getItemName(item)
            print(f"Item name is: {item_name}\n")
            if item_name == ItemName:
                print("Item found")
                # self.verifyPresence(menupage.AddToBucket)
                print("presenting item")
                self.verifyClickable(menupage.AddToBucket)
                print("click verfied")
                menupage.clickAddToBucket(item)
                break
            else:
                print("Item not found")
def go_to_menu(self):
        header = Header(self.driver)
        self.closePopup()
        header.click_sidenavbar()
        self.verifyClickable(header.ExploreMenuSidenav)
        header.click_explore_menu_sidenav()
```

Testcase:

```
def test_delivery_order(self):
        self.go_to_menu()
        self.add_item_to_cart("Krunch Burger")
```

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happened.  Please post the full error traceback message.

Comment: I posted the complete error